# How to maintain up-to-date version of git repository for non-git collaborators

Tags: git, github, collaboration

I have private git repository with multiple contributors. I would like to have up-to-date version of repository's master branch in network drive so that everyone (including the ones that doesn't use git) would have access to tools in the repo.

I have understood that this could be possible with git hooks, but I'm not sure how or what would be the best practice to do so.

Directory in the network drive should be just a clone of git repository's master and if it is accidentally modified, it should be cleaned whenever someone commits to master next time.

Edit: Most of contributors and collaborators work with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you setup a [webhook](https://help.github.com/articles/about-webhooks/) which will listen for push events and automatically update a local repo for you.

See for instance [this webhook](https://gist.github.com/cowboy/619858) (or [this one](https://gist.github.com/phedoreanu/11321236)):

```
<?php
// Use in the "Post-Receive URLs" section of your GitHub repo.
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_GITHUB_EVENT'] == 'push') {
  shell_exec( 'cd /path/to/network/drive/git-repo/ && git reset --hard HEAD && git pull' );
}
?>hi
```

This however supposes you have a full clone of the repo on the network drive.
Since it is a *private* repo, I would rather only have a working tree (no history) on it, meaning my webhook would do:

```
git --work-tree=/path/to/network/drive/git-repo checkout --force
```

Comment: I was wondering if this works on Windows since most of contributors work with Windows with no admin rights. And does it cause problems if you try to push to github when you are not connected to same network that network drive is. This is not usually the case, but I don't want others to get any weird error messages since they use git from github desktop client and are not interested to mess around with git.

Comment: @Lesenger It does work just fine: I don't have admin privileges on my Windows machine either at work. The network path is just there for other to read, not to modify or push. Any push is done from a regular local repo.

Comment: I'm still a little confused about webhooks. Where I even put these webhooks? GitHub repository settings have section 'Add webhook', but it have fields for 'Payload url', 'content type' and 'secret'. Also I don't quite understand what way are webhook commands executed. What exectly happens after someone pushes to repo? Bare with me. I'm not at all familiar with these server side stuff.

Comment: @Lesenger webhooks are there because GitHub cannot execute any custom program on its side for security reason. What it can do (and does through webhook) is send to an url of your chosing a JSON payload which represents the event associated to that webhook. You then listen for that payload and activate a program of your own on your side (which you have full control of)

Answer (score 0):

You need hook on push event (see [here](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/)). Whenever you receive request from this hook, you can do

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

This will fetch updates from 'origin' repository and change your local 'master' branch to the same state as remote 'master'.